# @odata.nextLink missing when trying to get places from Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have the following code to get places from Microsoft Graph:

```
    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>() { new QueryOption("$count", "true") };         
    var roomUrl = graphClient.Places.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.room");
    var response = await new GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest(roomUrl, graphClient, queryOptions).Top(100).GetAsync();                    
    var nextPageUrl = response.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.nextLink", out object nextLink) ? nextLink.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

On running this, I see ***@odata.nextLink*** value is missing from the response (there should be a next page link). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

- Some queries results in large list which can be limited in size for each page by using query `$top` to some number.In that case if results are more than that number @odata.nextLink value will be appeared in response .
- But if the results are "less or equal" to the queried limit and there contains no more results or page than that, then ***`@odata.nextLink property is not present that contains a URL to the next page of results in the response indicating, there are no more results than we got currently.`***

I have only one count in result when queried for getting places and so could not get nextlink property.

***For example***. Here I tried to get top 100 users.

> ```
> GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
> var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
> {
>   new QueryOption("$count", "true")
> };
>
> var users = await graphClient.Users
>   .Request( queryOptions )
>   .Top(100)
>   .GetAsync();
> ```

The response is exhausted and so no next page link as page has complete result .

[image]

In the below query I requested for top 5 results in one page, so it responded with @odata.nextLink property as the actual results have more than the 5 count and requires further pages to display next results.

> ```
> var users = await graphClient.Users
>   .Request( queryOptions )
>   .Top(5)
>   .GetAsync();
> ```

[image]

**Reference** : [Paging Microsoft Graph data in your app - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging)

Comment: I have added 1000 rooms in my demo tenant. The url I use to get places should give next page link.

Comment: Same here, I have more than 100 rooms and have used $top=100 in the Uri, but the @odata.nextlink isn't provided by Microsoft. This must be a bug.